# Codeigniter making image upload optional in a form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form with three fields- one input field, one textarea and an image upload. 
The form works fine for uploading image when I fill everything and select an image to upload but when I do not select an image it shows select and image. I want the form to submit even if the user does not upload an image. I am sure I had a solution yesterday for this but it stopped working today. 
Controller :

```
        function store()
{
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

        $this->load->model('campus_m');
                    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
                    $config['max_size'] = '100';
                    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
                    $config['max_height']  = '768';
                    $config['file_name'] = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i','-',iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT',$this->input->post('name')));
                    $config['file_name'] = trim($config['file_name'],'-').now().'.jpg';                         

                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

                        $this->load->library('form_validation');

                        $this->form_validation->set_rules('goods', 'Goods', 'required');
                        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|max_length[12]');
                        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                        {
                                $this->load->view('campus_write_v');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                    if (empty($_FILES['userfile'])) {
                    print_r($_FILES['userfile']);
                                if(!$query = $this->campus_m->create_review("Marla-overdoses1360186300.jpg")){
                                    $data['write_campus'] = 'The answer has not been stored.';
                                    $this->load->view('campus_write_v', $data);
                                    }
                                else {
                                    $data['write_campus'] = 'The answer has been stored. ';
                                    $this->load->view('campus_write_v', $data);
                                }   
                                    }
                                    else{
                                         if($this->upload->do_upload()){
                                if(!$query = $this->campus_m->create_review($config['file_name'])){
                                    $data['write_campus'] = 'The answer has not been stored.';
                                    $this->load->view('campus_write_v', $data);
                                    }
                                else {
                                    $data['write_campus'] = 'The answer has been stored. ';
                                    $this->load->view('campus_write_v', $data);
                                }                                               
                                    }
                            else
                            {
                                 $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                                 foreach ($error as $rows => $r) {
                                 echo $r ;                                 
                                 }
                                    $this->load->view('campus_write_v');                             
                            }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(isset($_FILES))
    {

          if(empty($_FILES['file']['name']))
          {
            //logic here    
          }else{
                if(//validation here )
                {
                   //logic here
                }

          }

    }
```

Comment: I did try it before but it gives an error for the image uploading and does not upload the image and instead just saves the name of the default file into the database. It does the execute the "else" statement but "if" block which contains the "empty" clause is being executed everytime .

Array ( [name] => images (1).jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php3EC6.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 9852 )

Comment: the answer is that $_FILES is not empty if you var_dump($_FILES) without anything in it it will return an array with some values making the empty($_FILES) return false, you must test first if it is `isset` then you will know that a file upload has been submitted, then you will detect if the file has a name, looking at your code you just tested the whole file,

Comment: I did try it with
if (empty($_FILES['userfile']['userfile']))
but still it did with the name included "userfile" is also the name of the file .

Comment: there is no attribute in php for file that goes by the name userfile, only `name`,`size`,`type`,`tmp_name`,`error` . http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php look at the manual you have to use it as `$_FILES['userfile']['name']`

Comment: @tomexans the input for file upload is this :
<input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile" size="20" />

Comment: @user1953363 then you will use that as `$_FILES['userfile']['name']` the file you uploaded will be stored in an array with a key of `userfile`